# reactjs for loop is stopping at 1 for some reason and issue with trying to use set state in a loop

Tags: reactjs

```
class Mailbox extends Component {
  state = {
    data: {
      emailSubject: "",
      emailDate: "",
      emailFrom: "",
    },
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const db = firebase.firestore();
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        var user = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
        let cityRef = db.collection("Users").doc(user);
        let getDoc = cityRef
          .get()
          .then((doc) => {
            if (!doc.exists) {
              console.log("No such document!");
            } else {
              console.log("Document data:", doc.data());

              for (let z = 0; z < 10; z++) {
                console.log(z);
                let data = doc.data();
                let emailBody = data.EmailBody[z];
                let emailsubject = data.EmailSubject;
                let emailSubject = emailsubject[z];
                let oldDate = data.EmailDate[z].seconds;
                var date = new Date(oldDate * 1000);
                let NewDate = date.valueOf();
                let emailDateYear = new Date(NewDate).getFullYear();
                let emailDateMonth = new Date(NewDate).getMonth();
                let emailDateDay = new Date(NewDate).getDate();

                let emailFrom = data.EmailFrom[z].value[z].address;

                console.log("FROMMMMM" + date);

                let emailDate =
                  emailDateMonth + "/" + emailDateDay + "/" + emailDateYear;

                this.setState({
                  emailSubject,
                  emailDate,
                  emailFrom,
                });
                console.log("STATE" + emailDate);
              }
            }
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log("Error getting document", err);
          });
      }
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <>
```

So basically what I am trying to do here is inside my database I have items stores under arrays such as EmailBody[1] EmailBody[2], etc that I need to fetch from the database and pass along into setState so I can pass them along as props into a component. I tried setting up this for loop using z as a variable and then having it loop adding z as the array number so each loop it pulls the next array of info and saves it into state. The thing is the loop only seems to run 0, 1 and then stop as I console logged z after the start of the loop and that is where it stops. So I am not sure why that is happening, and second, I am wondering if because I am looping and setting state, if each loop its over writing the previous saved state, instead of adding multiple values to the state like I want, causing only a single value to be saved in state. So I was hoping to get some advice on this. Thanks so much =]

Update:

I added this

```
class Mailbox extends Component {
  state = {
    data: [], // an empty array, that will be replaced by the one with all the data
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const db = firebase.firestore();
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        var user = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
        let cityRef = db.collection("Users").doc(user);
        let getDoc = cityRef
          .get()
          .then((doc) => {
            if (!doc.exists) {
              console.log("No such document!");
            } else {
              console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
              let allEmails = []; // array for the downloaded emails

              for (let z = 0; z < 100; z++) {
                console.log(z);
                let data = doc.data();
                let emailBody = data.EmailBody[z];
                let emailSubject = data.EmailSubject[z]; // added the missing index
                let oldDate = data.EmailDate[z].seconds;
                var date = new Date(oldDate * 1000);
                let NewDate = date.valueOf();
                let emailDateYear = new Date(NewDate).getFullYear();
                let emailDateMonth = new Date(NewDate).getMonth();
                let emailDateDay = new Date(NewDate).getDate();

                let emailFrom = data.EmailFrom[z].value[z].address;

                console.log("FROMMMMM" + date);

                let emailDate =
                  emailDateMonth + "/" + emailDateDay + "/" + emailDateYear;

                allEmails.push({
                  // pushing the current email to the end of the array
                  emailSubject,
                  emailDate,
                  emailFrom,
                });
                console.log("STATE" + emailDate);
              }
              this.setState({ data: allEmails }); // adding all the emails to the state at once
            }
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log("Error getting document", err);
          });
      }
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div id="ZenTitle">
          <h1>ZenMail Mailbox</h1>
        </div>

        <div id="MainArea" className="MainArea">
          <Popup
            trigger={
              <button className="ComposeButton">
                <i class="fas fa-pen-square" style={{ color: "white" }}></i>{" "}
                Compose
              </button>
            }
            position="center center"
            contentStyle={{
              backgroundColor: "#465775",
              width: "98%",
              height: "80%",
              color: "white",
              paddingTop: "25px",
              borderRadius: "25px",
            }}
            arrowStyle={{
              display: "none",
            }}
          >
            <div>Compose New Email</div>
            <br />
            <NormEdit />
          </Popup>

          <Button className="RefreshButton">
            <i style={{ color: "black" }} class="fas fa-sync"></i>
          </Button>
          <Button className="FavButton">
            <i style={{ color: "black" }} class="fas fa-star"></i>
          </Button>
          <Button className="DeleteButton">
            <i style={{ color: "black" }} class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
          </Button>
          <Form>
            <FormGroup>
              <Label></Label>
              <Input className="EmailSearch" placeholder="Search Emails..." />
            </FormGroup>
          </Form>

          <Popup
            trigger={
              <button className="SettingsButton">
                <i style={{ color: "black" }} class="fas fa-cog"></i>
              </button>
            }
            position="right center"
            contentStyle={{
              backgroundColor: "#465775",
              width: "98%",
              height: "80%",
              color: "white",
              paddingTop: "25px",
              borderRadius: "25px",
            }}
            arrowStyle={{
              display: "none",
            }}
          >
            <div>Account Settings</div>
          </Popup>
          <Inbox />
          <div className="IncomingArea">
            {this.state.data.map((value, index) => (
              <SingleEmail
                Subject={value.emailSubject}
                From={value.emailFrom}
                Date={value.emailDate}
              />
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default Mailbox;
```

but now my component SingleEmail does not show up at all

The loop issue I figured out atleast

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on how to debug your code.

Comment: Do all your arrays inside the loop have a length greater than or equal to 10?

Comment: loop issue was related to my fromEmail only going to 2 in the database while others were higher so I fixed the loop issue atleast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am wondering if because I am looping and setting state, if each loop its over writing the previous saved state, instead of adding multiple values to the state like I want

This is exactly your issue - your state isn't an array at all, so it can't store more than a single email. Also, I think you missed the index for `data.EmailSubject`

Here's the class with the state as an array

```
class Mailbox extends Component {
  state = {
    data: []  // an empty array, that will be replaced by the one with all the data
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const db = firebase.firestore();
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        var user = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
        let cityRef = db.collection("Users").doc(user);
        let getDoc = cityRef
          .get()
          .then((doc) => {
            if (!doc.exists) {
              console.log("No such document!");
            } else {
              console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
              let allEmails = []; // array for the downloaded emails

              for (let z = 0; z < 10; z++) {
                console.log(z);
                let data = doc.data();
                let emailBody = data.EmailBody[z];
                let emailSubject = data.EmailSubject[z];  // added the missing index
                let oldDate = data.EmailDate[z].seconds;
                var date = new Date(oldDate * 1000);
                let NewDate = date.valueOf();
                let emailDateYear = new Date(NewDate).getFullYear();
                let emailDateMonth = new Date(NewDate).getMonth();
                let emailDateDay = new Date(NewDate).getDate();

                let emailFrom = data.EmailFrom[z].value[z].address;

                console.log("FROMMMMM" + date);

                let emailDate =
                  emailDateMonth + "/" + emailDateDay + "/" + emailDateYear;

                allEmails.push({  // pushing the current email to the end of the array
                  emailSubject,
                  emailDate,
                  emailFrom,
                });
                console.log("STATE" + emailDate);
              }
              setState({data: allEmails}); // adding all the emails to the state at once
            }
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log("Error getting document", err);
          });
      }
    });
  }
  // a simple map() to display the emails
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        {this.state.data.map((value, index) => (
          <ul key={index}>
            <li>{value.emailSubject}</li>
            <li>{value.emailDate}</li>
            <li>{value.emailFrom}</li>
          <ul/>
        ))}
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

(Btw you could also use the `map()` function to generate the `allEmails` array)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey I did this but when I added     {this.state.data.map((value, index) => ( to my component before passing the props into it, it causes my component to now show up on the page. I am guessing I handled that part wrong? do I need to add that to the page I am calling the props on and not the page I am passing the props to the component in? Check my post I added an update to show you what I did.

Comment: @CodingIsFun33 You don't have to change anything in the other components. The array is initially empty, that's why none of your ```<SingleEmail>``` components are showing up. It seems like the ```allEmails``` array is empty or the ```this.setState()``` isn't called for some reason. Could you check there is anything in the ```allEmails``` array after the for loop?

Comment: @CodingIsFun33 No problem! Just a side note: you can use ```console.log()``` with an unlimited number of arguments f ex ```console.log("STATE", allEmails)```. Browsers are really nice about variables, so the allEmails would be much more readable with this method. Anyway, glad I could help! :D

Comment: Thanks for the additional info =]